# How to use LIMIT in query in access, but not TOP

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to display 15 rows from queries but not first 15?

```
SELECT Abgänge.Vorgang, Abgänge.Date_SW_Drucken FROM Abgänge 
WHERE Abgänge.Bezahlung = "Bar" LIMIT 34,15;
```

How to transform this to access 2010?

Limit:

```
LIMIT from_record-1, count_record
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because there is no support for an offset in the Microsoft Access [`SELECT` syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821148.aspx). An option is to use `TOP` with `offset + limit` and skip `offset` rows manually. BTW: Using `TOP` or `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is not advisable as it can lead to inconsistent results.

You could also combine two queries with `TOP`, first selecting `limit + offset`, and then selecting only `offset`, for example

```
SELECT TOP 15 ...
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 49 ....
   FROM sometable
   ORDER BY somecolumn ASC
) a
ORDER BY somecolumn DESC
```

The only problem with this solution is that if there are less than 49 results from the subquery, then the offset will be less than 34.

If you need the result in a different order then you may need to add an additional 'layer' that applies that order.

Comment: @STTLCU If you have nothing constructive to contribute, then just don't comment. And this construct also applies to other SQL implementations that don't support `LIMIT` (or `ROWS`) with an offset.

Comment: Using a more serious tone, I'd advice against developing using MS Access because it lacks lot of features that are needed in a proper database: this will cause the developer a lot of issues and the need of improper workarounds (see this very answer for a live example) just to get simple task done. Given the fact that the asker is a novice and/or is just starting to develop, the advice of switching database may be the most effective one he's going to receive. Sure, learning how to master a platform has its merit, but I'd spend my effort toward learning an usable one like PostgreSQL or MariaDB

Comment: @STTLCU everything has its place. Access is a remarkable platform for RAD.