# [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause because of Offset and Limit

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-access

I am using php moreover, codeigniter to access an mdb file.
I connect and query the db when using the following:

```
$this->mov->query("Select * from Logger")->result_array();
```

So no issues there. The problems come up when i try to add a limit and offset to the query. As follows:

```
$this->mov->query("Select * from Logger Limit $limit offset $offset")->result_array();
```

I am sure that `$offset` and `$limit` are not empty.

I get the following error:

> Error Number: 37000
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.
>
> Select * from Logger Limit 10 offset 0
>
> Filename: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

I am more a Mysql oriented and do not have that much experience in MSAccess.

I am trying the workaround as suggestted in the comments and start using top but now i get this error:

Error Number: 37000

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The SELECT statement
>   includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or
>   missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.
>
> Select TOP 10 from Logger
>
> Filename: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LIMIT in query in access, but not TOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003553/how-to-use-limit-in-query-in-access-but-not-top)

Comment: There's no such thing as `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` in Access. Either use the workaround described there, or rework your application not to need it

Comment: I will try the work around but now top is giving another error. Edited the original post to show

Comment: `SELECT TOP 10 *`, not `SELECT TOP 10`. Now you're not selecting any fields.

Comment: and if i need for example just a selected fields (which include ex 01_Recipe_name) how can i make it> Regards and thanks for the help!

Comment: Eh... Please try a bit yourself. You can just select specific fields like in any normal query.

Comment: I have tried with no success. I will continue and will figure it out. Anyways thanks for the help. I am sure of i thing though. I will never use Access again!

Answer (score 0):

For those being redirected here i have an answer which up to now i didn't find any mistakes. Hope i do not find.
My problem was for pagination and adapting Limit and offset.
Here is a way i found for MSAccess pagination. Please if you find any mistakes don't hesitate to write:

```
Select TOP {Rows/Page} * from {table} where {ID} not in (Select {ID} from (Select Top {Offset} * from {table} order by {column}) as tbl1) order by {column}
```

Where:

```
{Rows/Page} = Records to show per page
{table} = Table is your table
{ID} = A unique column in your table
{column} = Column in your table to order by
```